# Remove empty lists json regex?

Tags: java, json, regex, string

I want to parse a json string and remove empty lists. Eg:

JSON string input:

```
{
  "rootname" : {
    "key1" : [ "lbl1", "lbl2" ],
    "key2" : 10,
    "key3" : [ ],
    "key4" : "hello",
    "key5" : []
  }
}
```

I want the output like:

```
{
  "rootname" : {
    "key1" : [ "lbl1", "lbl2" ],
    "key2" : 10,
    "key4" : "hello"
  }
}
```

The empty lists *rows* removed.

How can I do it with regex in java?

Comment: Why do you want to do that with Regex?

Comment: Why would you use a regex for this? Parse your JSON

Comment: check the if JSONArray.isNull();   if true then remove it

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse json here rather than using regex. Yet this can be solved by regex in the following way:

search by this:

```
\"[^"]*\"\s*:\s*\[\s*\],?
```

and replace by empty . i.e ""

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GU7aYT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Regexp sound like a funny choice to treat json, but if you want, you can do something like following:

```
/"[^"]*"\s*:\s*\[\s*\]\s*,?\s*//g
```

replacing `"[^"]*"\s*:\s*\[\s*\]\s*,?\s*` by nothing
(`\s*` matching series of spaces/tabs/new lines, `,?` matching when there is a coma or not)

Matching for example like
`"key3" : [ ],`
`"key5" : []`

```
"s0me_Other Key":[   

],
```

And so removing all found, including the potential following new line character !

But maybe a problem will be if there are empty arrays in others that would be empty after removing once empty arrays, like:

```
"key": [
   [ ]
]
// will be unchanged
```

or

```
"key": {
  "key2": []
}

// will become
"key": {}
```

Comment: How is that answer differ from the other answer provided earlier?

Comment: Yeah, is just equivalent; we posted at the same time I imagine, when I've done it, there was no other answers ^^

Comment: not a big deal dude, chill... btw there was one! just sort by older :)